# My Java Game that struggles with fps

Tags: java, frame-rate

Hello my name is Ryan and I'm currently developing my own 2D java game. Currently there are  a lot of objects within the game world. Upon a new start of the game, the world loads with 100 tress randomly positioned on it, made with the use of an arraylist and a tree class. My game uses a class called `checkcollisions` to check if the player is intersecting with any tress. This method is then put within the `update` method. When this method is not called I get an extra 100 FPS is there away I can still get this 100 fps but still check for collisions? I really need an FPS boost asas my game currently runs at 30-50 fps

here is the checkcollisions code:

```
public void checkCollisions() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.size(); i++) {
        if (player.getBounds().intersects(Placing_Objects.getSmall_Tree().get(i).getBounds())) {
            if (gotAxeOn) {Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i).health -= rand.nextInt(3);}
        }
        if (Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i).health <= 0) {
            Placing_Objects.removeSmall_Tree(Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i));
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Wood");
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Wood");
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Stick");
            Player.exp += rand.nextInt(3);
            challenges.choppedDownTrees += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your algorithm for checkCollisions, there may be the problem.

Comment: Without knowing what your `checkcollisions` method looks like, it's hard to help you improve it.  Are you calling this method every frame?  Presumably, the result will only change when they player moves; try calling it only when necessary.

Comment: You should show some code which you want to improve. Now we can only say that your collision detection method is probably slow :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'd like to help you, but you can't expect us to read your mind. Add some relevant code!

Comment: I expect you are brute force collision detection;  where everything is checked against everything.  This is painfully slow. Especially if your trees have many verticies. All good collision detection includes a broadphase where the question "**could** these two things collide"; usually based on boxes that contain the real collision geometry. Only if the broad phase has a collision does the narrow phase run its check

Comment: Improvements include partitioning your world, if you're over at x=100 you dont even need to check the trees in the x=0 - x=25 section;  further increasing efficiency

Comment: the code has been added and just to let u know, the code is in the update method. Also trees are randomly generated on a map

Comment: What does .getBounds() return, something simple (like a rectangle)or something complex?

Answer (score 3):

100 objects should easily be able to support collision checking at 100fps, especially in a 2D world. Therefore your algorithm is likely at fault.

It sounds like you brute force check each tree against the player; this can get very slow, especially if the trees' geometries are complex. This level of checking can be avoided by using 1 or more broad phases.

#### Broad phase

In a basic broad phase you check each object that could collide's **bounding box** against each other object's bounding box. It is not important that the bounding box be the precisely the shape of the object, just that it be relatively small, completely contain the object and be a simple shape (axis aligned rectangle is best). Only if this simple check for collision is passed is the more expensive narrow phase check made.

#### Spacial partitioning

A further refinement is to spacially seperate the region into larger boxes. Thereby allowing you to eliminate collisions against several trees at once.

These concepts are illustrated in the below diagram

[image]

Here the player is shown as a red circle; you can immediately see that there is no point checking any but two of the trees as only 2 trees are inside the same Large box as the player. On checking just the bounding box of those 2 trees you see only one of those could be colliding with the player; you check the fine geometry of the remaining tree to find that it also does not collide.

Comment: I have added the code, could you check it...

Comment: @user2876115 is the quoted code the code that runs slowly or new code?

Comment: the code i added was the code that was making my program run slow

Comment: @user2876115 Ok, but we need to see the code for getBounds() and intersects() to know whats wrong (or if you didn't write them then we need to know what class those methods belong to). We need to see more of your program