# Low FPS in Java

Tags: java, performance, frame-rate

Hello my name is Ryan and I'm currently developing my own 2D java game. Currently there are  a lot of objects within the game world. Upon a new start of the game, the world loads with 100 tress randomly positioned on it, made with the use of an arraylist and a tree class. My game uses a class called `checkcollisions` to check if the player is intersecting with any tress. This method is then put within the `update` method. When this method is not called I get an extra 100 FPS is there away I can still get this 100 fps but still check for collisions? I really need an FPS boost asas my game currently runs at 30-50 fps

here is the checkcollisions code:

```
public void checkCollisions() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.size(); i++) {
        if (player.getBounds().intersects(Placing_Objects.getSmall_Tree().get(i).getBounds())) {
            if (gotAxeOn) {Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i).health -= rand.nextInt(3);}
        }
        if (Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i).health <= 0) {
            Placing_Objects.removeSmall_Tree(Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i));
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Wood");
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Wood");
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Stick");
            Player.exp += rand.nextInt(3);
            challenges.choppedDownTrees += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The slow down could be caused by any number of function calls made in the checkCollisions function.  The interests() function called on the player is a probable culprit.

Comment: Run your game in a profiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My Java Game that struggles with fps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683731/my-java-game-that-struggles-with-fps)

Comment: @user2876115 A profiler will tell you how much time each method uses; allowing you to find the bottle neck. Most IDEs (for example netbeans) come with profilers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rearranged the code and it now works fine! Thank you to everyone who helped, i'm also sorry for posting this question many times...I'm new to this and didn't really know what I was doing. Once again thank you everyone you've helped a developer in need! Here's the new code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.size(); i++) {
        if (gotAxeOn) {
            if (player.getBounds().intersects(Placing_Objects.getSmall_Tree().get(i).getBounds())) {
                Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i).health -= rand.nextInt(3);
                }
        }
        if (Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i).health <= 0) {
            Placing_Objects.removeSmall_Tree(Placing_Objects.Small_Trees.get(i));
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Wood");
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Wood");
            Inventory.addItemToInv("Stick");
            Player.exp += rand.nextInt(3);
            challenges.choppedDownTrees += 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Only check for collisions with trees that are near to the player, or trees that are within the current visible rectangle. To do this efficiently, hold an array of objects that are visible and iterate only over those.

Comment: how would i check if each individual tree is in the visible rectangle(camera) without using a for loop?

Comment: You have to. That is something you cannot avoid. But once you found the visible objects, you can perform *ALL your game logic* on those, instead of everything. That would be a major improvement if you are having lots of objects.

Comment: could u show me a code sample, java or pseudo would be alright

Answer (score 2):

As Wilbert mentioned a kd-tree would be the perfect solution.
For a simple 2d game with a lot of non moving objects you can try a simpler approach:

First, set up all you trees as you have already done it:

[image]

Hold all these trees in your ArrayList.

No seperate your game field in x rectangles of the same size (for example 3x5=15) and check which tree intersects with which region. Save these calculations in a suitable data structure. For example:

```
HashMap<Rectangle, ArrayList<Tree>> fieldSperation;
```

[image]

The white number whithin the trees indicate which Rectangle they intersect. It is possible, that one tree intersects with more than one Rectangle. Then you have to hold a reference in two or more lists (example 6/7 or 7/12).

Last you can adapt your checkCollisions() method as follows:

```
public void checkCollisions() {
    // 1. check which Rectangle intersects with the player (can be a maximum of 4)
    for (Rectangle r : fieldSeperation.keySet()) {
         if (playerRect.intersect(r)) {
             // 2. do your collision detection with those trees which are intersecting with those
             // trees which are intersecting with the rectangles from 1.)
             for (List<Tree> ts : fieldSeperation.get(r)) {
                 // your old code here
             }
         }
     }
}
```

I am pretty sure this technique will be enough to fit your perfomance requirements.

Comment: Could I still use this method if the trees move

Comment: If a tree moves, you have to recalcualte its intersecting rectangles. So remove it from all the lists in which it is contained, then add it to the new corresponding lists.

Answer (score 1):

Use a spatial data structure for collision testing. With such a structure, you can reduce the number of tests by a large amount.

Two simple yet efficient structures for 2d would be the [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

A related question with links to a kd-tree implementation in java can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253767/kdtree-implementation-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Do not check for collisions in Swing event dispatch thread. Create a concurrent thread that does that and event thread simply assigns them to it. Reduce the amount of checked collisions by max only check on trees that are on screen.